# What process would I go through to design (that included custom LEDs) and have a custom case manufactured (in moderate quantities) for Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: case

I've seen small runs of [custom](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GN9JZBS) [cases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072ND582W) made and I'd like to get some made (where I could order 250-500 of them at a time), but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing it.

I'd like to include LEDs in the case that are controlled by the GPIO but I'm not sure where to start.

For context, I use them in an education setting ([www.smile-pi.org](http://www.smile-pi.org)) and currently use an 8x8 LED hat to show a graphic when the Pi is in use. I'd like to have some cases made that have this "smile" built-in, but I'm not sure where to start.

To help make sure this question is on topic, perhaps this will help: **What are the steps I would take to have a custom case manufactured that included controllable LEDs in the top half of the case that would be controlled through the GPIO?**

I’d imagine it’d be something like this:

1. Design circuit as mentioned above.
2. ?? Turn it into a printed circuit board with surface mount LEDs?? What kind of company does that?
3. Design the case (maybe 3D print prototypes
4. ?? Get a company to mass produce out of plastic.. but what kind of company does that? What do they need from me in order to do that.

So there are some gaps in my knowledge, maybe it’s terminology, what do you call what I’m trying to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Apparently my offer to engage and develop a solution with you was deleted by a moderator. I can definitely point you towards some manufacturers that will fulfill your desire, but still a case design would be needed as would a pcb for the smile when the pi is active. Hopefully this answer doesn't get removed.

Comment: You may want to 3d print some prototypes.

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic. You'll have to shop around.

Comment: @user2636268 I got your email through other channels and will reach out directly, thanks.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev that’s the problem though, what I’m asking about isn’t “shopping around”. As far as I could find there isn’t a store somewhere that does what I’m looking for. I don’t even know where to start or what I would need to do in order to make this happen. I have a feeling I need to design a circuit and case, but then what? I’m not even sure of the question I need to ask

Comment: @NomadMaker I have 3D printed some cases... but now what? That’s the essence of my question. Who do I go to with a design and say “can you manufacture 200 of these for me?” I haven’t found the equivalent of Printful for Raspberry Pi cases. Thanks

Comment: I updated my question, I know SE doesn’t usually want opinionated questions or recommendations for specific services, however I think this could be a useful question if it outlined the process to do something like this and perhaps included links to an example of a company (without implied endorsement) that did something like this. I feel it would give future readers a place to start at least. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Googling for "plastic case production Germany" instantly found me a dozen of factories such as [this one](https://www.wag.de/en/services/injection-moulding/). Replace "Germany" with your country or state and start calling: not every factory will accept to produce only 200 pieces.